# How to substract 1 from bidirectional iterator

Tags: c++, stl

I have iterator I dont want to change, but I would like to assign another iterator to the value of that iterator -1, so
`it2 = --it1;`
is out of the question.
Problem:
`it2 = it1-1;`
doesnt work.

> error: no match for 'operator-' in 'bigger - 1'
>   c++/4.1.1/bits/stl_bvector.h:182: note: candidates are: ptrdiff_t
>   std::operator-(const std::_Bit_iterator_base&, const
>   std::_Bit_iterator_base&)

ofc I could do

```
it2 = --it1;
it1++;
```

but that is horrible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++11, use [`std::prev`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/prev/) from the header `<iterator>`:

```
it2 = std::prev(it1);
```

Prior to that, you're stuck making a copy and advancing the copy by -1 yourself:

```
it2 = it1;
std::advance(it2, -1);
```

or:

```
it2 = it1;
it2--;
```

Comment: since im const nazi stuck on old compiler i used a tmp to make both it1 and it2 const :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
it2 = it1; 
-- it2;
```

`it1` will not be modified.

Comment: The other answer of `std::prev()` is a better (i.e. clearer) way to do it presuming your compiler supports C++11 additions. These days, generally all *modern* compilers on *common* platforms do.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes I prefer `--` as well (also I work with older compilers more often than not). But so far it's 6 beholders to 0.

Comment: One benefit of `--` over `std::prev` is it can be an interface provided by non-STL iterators, whereas `std::prev` works with STL types (the OP did tag as `stl`, however).